# If $A$ is nonempty open bounded subset of $\mathbb R$ then $\sup A$ is not in $A$

Tags: real-analysis

$A$ is open iff there is neighbourhood of every element of $A$ which subset of $A$

$A$ is closed iff complete of $A$ is closed

I think must recall cluster point:
$X$ is cluster point iff there is neighbourhood of $x$ in $A$

Comment: If a number $x$ is in $A$, then since $A$ is open, $A$ must contain numbers larger than $x$. Can this happen if $x$ is the supremum of $A$?

Comment: Do you mean that $A$ is closed iff the complement is open? I.E. $\mathbb{R}-A$ is open?

Comment: Yes the set is in R